# Spring DateTime Conversion service exception

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc, datetime

I'm getting this exception:

Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type `java.util.Date for property startTime; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Date for value 10:00; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

when trying to input the time and send via form to controller.

I had the same issue with the date but managed to fix it using an example that I found online:

```
 <bean id="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</bean>

<bean id="appointment" class="com.nw.model.Appointment">
    <property name="theDate">
        <bean factory-bean="dateFormat" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="22/05/1983" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="startTime">
        <bean factory-bean="timeFormat" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="22/05/1983 10:00:34" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="endTime">
        <bean factory-bean="timeFormat" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="22/05/1983 10:00:23" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

'theDate' is not throwing any error, it seems to be fine.  It does get returned back to me incorrectly when the form fails to post but that's another issue altogether - maybe this fix will solve that.

The date - when selected from a  date picker will parse fine, the result when the form fails to post and is returned is `Sun Oct 18 00:00:00 BST 2015` - if i try and send with this date then it throws and exception here too.

I added a small piece for the time to my config so that now the complete formatter part is:

```
<bean id="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</bean>

<bean id="timeFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="HH:mm" />
</bean>


<bean id="appointment" class="com.nw.model.Appointment">
    <property name="theDate">
        <bean factory-bean="dateFormat" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="22/05/1983" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="startTime">
        <bean factory-bean="timeFormat" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="22/05/1983 10:00:34" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="endTime">
        <bean factory-bean="timeFormat" factory-method="parse">
            <constructor-arg value="22/05/1983 10:00:23" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The form is using thymeleaf and the fields of the model are Date objects.

I can post the remainder of the model / form if required.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The specific exception that you're getting is throwing me a bit, so I'd like to see the whole stack trace.

That being said, you are trying to parse `String`s with format `dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss` using the format string `HH:mm`. This causes a `ParseException` since it doesn't know what to do with the leading date portion of the `String` (`dd/MM/yy`).

Try the following:

```
<bean id="timeFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="dd/MM/yy HH:mm" />
</bean>
```

That will capture the full instant of time that you are trying to represent (although it will use the system's timezone, which you might not want).